# Android Emulator Camera Not Working after Android Studio update 2019

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator-plugin

After updating Android Studio to v. 3.5.3 Camera not working. The Camera does not work in the app I was working on and does not work separately from the app. (By starting Camera without the app). The camera worked before the update. Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

OS v. - Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

Android Emulator v. 29.3.2.

Android SDK Platform-Tools v. 29.05.

Android Tools v. 26.1.1.

Android Gradle v. 3.5.3.

Camera version: Camera(deprecated).

APIs targeted  16-29.

Also went through a codelab lesson on CameraX- first 6 sections of https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/ using APIs 21-29 and and could not get CameraX to work correctly in emulator.

Emulator camera works fine with Android Studio 3.5.2 and emulator 29.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Filed bug report with Google approximately January 3, 2020. Sent Google logcat files on January 3. Installed new version of Android Emulator (v. 29.3.4) on January 6,2020. Quick inspection verifies camera works in new emulator.